# Items within NestedScrollView need to be clicked twice after scrolling to top or bottom

Tags: android

I have a `NestedScrollView` within a `CoordinatorLayout`. Within the `NestedScrollView` I have a `LinearLayout` with a few components, some of which are buttons. There are no customizations to the components, I only have the standard layout parameters.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I fling the `NestedScrollView` to the top or to the bottom and see the **overscroll edges**, all buttons on the view do not handle any touch the first time they're pressed. A **second touch** is required and from then on any button will respond the first time. It's as if the focus gets lost and the first touch is to get it back to the view and the second one is the one that's really handled.

I've tried:

1. Setting `focusable=true`, `focusableInTouchMode=true` and `descendantFocusability=afterDescendants`. Doesn't work.
2. Overriding `NestedScrollView`'s `onScrollChanged` to detect when we reach the top/bottom and manually request the focus for the closest view. Doesn't work, strange things happen, such as a view on the Toolbar getting focused...
3. Simulating a touch event on the `LinearLayout` via `dispatchTouchEvent()`.

None of them have worked. Many thanks in advance if you can help me see the light!

EDIT: seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829976/onclick-method-not-working-properly-after-nestedscrollview-scrolled).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick method not working properly after NestedScrollView scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829976/onclick-method-not-working-properly-after-nestedscrollview-scrolled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178041

As of today, it's not fixed in the support library v23.