# Android - the item inside RecyclerView can't be clicked after scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I just upgraded to API 26 and support library 26.0.2. But I found that my `RecyclerView` items is not clickable right after the scrolling. If you wait for a second, it will work. But if you click the item immediately, it won't. Even if the `RecyclerView` is not scrolling at all(e.g. has scrolled to the top).

When I downgraded to support library 25.4.0 everything goes fine again.
The key point is that my `RecyclerView` is in a `CoordinatorLayout` and has a `SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL` flag on my `Toolbar` of the `AppBarLayout`. If I don't use this flag, then this problem will disappear. So I think it's a hidden behavior change of support library 26.

I've tried to add `focusable="false"` to the `CoordinatorLayout` but still had no luck.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? Because it's really annoying to click twice to trigger the click event.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinateLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@null">
        <include
                android:id="@+id/dynamicActionBarHolder"
                layout="@layout/dynamic_action_bar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/pullToRefreshMailRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mailRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT

I think the problem is the `scrollState` of the `RecyclerView`. When it's stopped scrolling, it's not changed to `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` immediately. Looking into the source code of `RecyclerView`, I found there's a `ViewFlinger` controlling the scroll state. When I fling down to scroll to the top, it's not calling `setScrollState(SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)` immediately, instead, it wait for a while to trigger this method. The more fast I fling, the more time I need to wait. It just like the RecyclerView is still scrolling in the background. Because the `scroller.isFinished()` doesn't return true right after the `RecyclerView` stop scrolling when it touched the top. Maybe it's a bug of the `RecyclerView` when it's in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Can you delete the `app:layout_behavior` in `SwipeRefreshLayout ` and try again ?

Comment: It still not clickable after scrolling. The only way to make it work is to set the flag to 0, `setScrollFlags(0)`.

Answer (score 42):

Found a way to force the scroll state to be idle.
Waiting for google to fix this bug.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean requestCancelDisallowInterceptTouchEvent = getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING;
    boolean consumed = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    final int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if( requestCancelDisallowInterceptTouchEvent ){
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                // only if it touched the top or the bottom. Thanks to @Sergey's answer.
                if (!canScrollVertically(-1) || !canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    // stop scroll to enable child view to get the touch event
                    stopScroll();
                    // do not consume the event
                    return false;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return consumed;
}
```

EDIT

The issue has been fixed in support library 27.0.1.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-1

> After a user scrolls, they cannot click on an item in a RecyclerView. (AOSP issue 66996774)

Updated on Nov 17, 2017

Some users reported that this problem is not fixed in support library 27.0.1.
The issue tracker is here.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774

So you may choose to use this official workaround.
https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2

Or use this one here.

Comment: `The issue has been fixed in support library 27.0.1.` this doesn't actually fix it for me at all :P 27.0.2 (haven't had the time for the workarounds yet)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce We all knew that Google is not good at fixing bugs. I'm still waiting for them to fix the chromium bug which makes my app crashed 200 times a day. And it's been almost a year.

Comment: Not good at fixing bugs isnt the problem, developers did fix it manually. The problem is Google is also good at creating bugs. You know, Im afraid-ed to updating Google's API.

Comment: @nyconing Totally agree with you. It's always a disaster.

Comment: I'm not using Coordinate layout and AppBarLayout,  Having horizontal recylerview inside Relativelayout. I have a requirement, as the recylerview need to scroll automatically, need to find the center item in screen, also need to click the items while scrolling. I have achieved auto scrolling. But click  on items not working. I have raised a question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959211/item-click-is-not-working-while-auto-scroll-in-recyclerview

Comment: @KimiChiu you deserve a 1000 thumbs up.. I just override onInterceptTouchEvent of my recyclerview with your solution and it worked like a charm.. cheers to you!

Comment: Issue is still present in androidX as well.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to use this code? I have a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview, which is inside a Nestedscrollview. I suppose I have to subclass the parent recyclerview and override this method. Please tell me if that's not how it needs to be done.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you very much for this question and your answer! It saved me a lot of time. Sorry for posting this as an answer. I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I also noticed this issue, but as a new Android developer I didn't realize it's a bug inside the new support library.

What I wanted to suggest is also adding this check:

```
if( requestCancelDisallowInterceptTouchEvent ){
    if (!canScrollVertically(-1) || !canScrollVertically(1)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It will make sure that while the RecyclerView is actually being scrolled, we don't click on any item.

As I understand, it's an expected behaviour. However, your answer helped me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494490/recyclerview-items-clicking-while-scrolling).

Comment: You're right. I'm using `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` of the `LayoutManager` to check if my `RecyclerView` is already scrolled to the top or to the bottom. Didn't know there's a `canScrollVertically` method. This is way more elegant than using `LayoutManager`.

Comment: Hi @KimiChiu! Once again, I could only comment to my answer :) Hey! It looks like they have fixed this bug inside the Revision 27.0.1. And I bet it was your report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774 :)) At least the email starts with "ki...@gmail.com"

Comment: Looks like the problem is still there in 27.0.1. I've edited my answer as your suggestion in case someone have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a source code that solved this issue. This issue occur because of AppBarLayout's behavior (AppBarLayout.Behavior). This source code provide an extending or a customizing behavior of behavior of AppBarLayout and set it into the AppBarLayout with introduction of usage both in xml directly or java. I can only explain briefly about it because the source has license that you must read it too. Please see the solution in this link:
https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2