# Enable click items, even when scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch, android-touch-event

Normal behaviour : When we fling scroll recycler view, items will scroll, then tap, RV will stops scroll, not perform item click.

What I need: Stop scroll + perform item click!

Any hacky way?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569656/8863321)

I want to add some more code...

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569656/8863321

    boolean requestCancelDisallowInterceptTouchEvent = getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING;
    boolean consumed = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    final int action = e.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if( requestCancelDisallowInterceptTouchEvent ){
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                // stop scroll to enable child view get the touch event
                stopScroll();
                // not consume the event
                return false;
            }
            break;
    }

    return consumed;
```

}
}

This is very rare scenario, but this trick may help somebody in future!