# Item click is not working, while auto scroll in recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, onitemclick

I have used the following code to autoscroll the Horizontal recyclerview.

```
private final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerViewDate.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);
            setDateValue();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);
        }
    };


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_center_item_finder);
        txtSelected=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSelected);
        getRecyclerviewData();
        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 100);
    }
```

But I'm not able to perform click on recycler items, while scrolling. 
Found this solution, created a custom recyclerview. [Android - the item inside RecyclerView can't be clicked after scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452465/android-the-item-inside-recyclerview-cant-be-clicked-after-scroll/46453825#46453825)
Still click not working.

Comment: I amde a custom class extend Recylerview and put this answer into this and it worked good for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569656/5773037