# CoordinatorLayout and toolbar and TabLayout sometimes cannot work move right and left scroll

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I make the collapse toolbar activity use the CoordinatorLayout.

## 1. main_activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_space"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/fabButton_menu"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/color_family"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        style="@style/FabStyle_Normal"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## 2. code

```
pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pagerAdapter.addFragment(new TabFragment_Home(), "T1");
pagerAdapter.addFragment(new TabFragment_Pharm(),"T2");
pagerAdapter.addFragment(new TabFragment_Family(), "T3");
pagerAdapter.addFragment(new TabFragment_Board(), "T4");

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, false);
```

This code is very simple and basic code.
I have one question the scroll action please see the image below.

[image]

[image]

Question: why cannot scroll move right? this is bug or my mistake? please let me know. thanks

Comment: you want to scroll tab right side and move to second tab using scrolling?

Comment: ah... my mistake questions.. use the left scroll move to second tab

Comment: have you tried my answers?

Comment: yes, input code this tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE); but still same.. I use the example code [here](https://github.com/teju/Example_Code/tree/master/CollapsingToolbarDemo-master)

Comment: plz find my another answer and try it.

Comment: I founds bug to 25 version my self. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452465/android-the-item-inside-recyclerview-cant-be-clicked-after-scroll/47111082#47111082

Answer (score 0):

please add below lines in your tablayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/myPrimaryColor"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

programmatically you can also set scrollable mode:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in tablayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: same problem.. : (