# Buttons inside fragments not firing first time in scroll view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, onclicklistener

In my app I have 5 fragments in home page..

I am using Relative Layout to display five fragments. I tired linear Layout also it does not work..

This is my layout code

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >
        <fragment android:name="com.example.Fragment1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_need_card" />

        <fragment android:name="com.example.Fragment2"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_discussion" />

        <fragment android:name="com.example.Fragment3"
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_askapro" />


        <fragment android:name="com.example.Fragment4"
            android:id="@+id/fragment4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/askapro"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment3" />


        <fragment android:name="com.example.Fragment5"
            android:id="@+id/fragment5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/recent_articles" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

by Default 2 fragments visible in screen,for next 3 fragments user has to scroll vertically..

public class Fragment3 extends BaseFragment {

```
public Fragment3() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);
    CardView b= (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(),DummyEvent.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



    return  v;
}
```

this onclick listener never fired first time ,i have to click twice..

I think the third fragment is not getting focused.may be i bind the fragment in layout? any one has idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: I feel this line `android:layout_below="@+id/askapro"` is a typo. Please check it. It should be `android:layout_below="@id/fragment3"`

Comment: @Asthme provide your fragment3 xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a bug in android support library NestedScrollView. It can be found here : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178041

This issue will most probably be fixed in next release. Till then you can see the workaround from this post :
[onClick method not working properly after NestedScrollView scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829976/onclick-method-not-working-properly-after-nestedscrollview-scrolled/32783524#32783524)

Comment: @Asthme i did some research on your problem its bug in android support libarary.check my edited answer for workaround

Answer (score 0):

If you are using androidX, use this update `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'.` or above.