# onClick method inside RecyclerView not working after NestedScrollView scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I checked [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829976/onclick-method-not-working-properly-after-nestedscrollview-scrolled) cause it's very similar, but the Google's bug have been fixed in current versions, but I still having the problem.

I have an RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView, after NestedScrollView scrolled if I click on item inside RecyclerView, onClick method does not work propertly.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I found the solution [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774), we need:

```
public class FixAppBarLayoutBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

public FixAppBarLayoutBehavior() {
    super();
}

public FixAppBarLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target,
                           int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
            dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
    stopNestedScrollIfNeeded(dyUnconsumed, child, target, type);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                              View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    stopNestedScrollIfNeeded(dy, child, target, type);
}

private void stopNestedScrollIfNeeded(int dy, AppBarLayout child, View target, int type) {
    if (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH) {
        final int currOffset = getTopAndBottomOffset();
        if ((dy < 0 && currOffset == 0)
                || (dy > 0 && currOffset == -child.getTotalScrollRange())) {
            ViewCompat.stopNestedScroll(target, ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and, in our AppBarLayout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
         ...
        app:layout_behavior="your.package.FixAppBarLayoutBehavior" 
         ... 
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day!

Comment: I don't have an appbar layout. what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` shouldn't permit nested scrolling, so it must have `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```