# First click on a View is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` which needs to be clickable inside a `NestedScrollView` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and almost all the time the first time I click it it simply doesn't work, I must click it another time.

[image: Click error]

Clickable `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/qr_code_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
```

- [This is the `NestedScrollView` container where
  the clickable item resides.](https://pastebin.com/fhfzVbEt)

**EDIT: Okay this is very weird, if I wait some seconds before trying to click the View, it works the first time. It only fails if I click it just after scrolling to the bottom.**

Comment: Maybe with the first click you make clickable true, then the second touch make it false, please check your  generateQr() thoroughly, and let me know.

Comment: The problem is in focus. First click well set focus and second will actually call onclick method. If you want to set `focusable` to `true` and still get first click the check the `setOnFocusChangeListener` in documentation.

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn I have tried removing the line where I set clickable to `false` and the problem is still there. I don't think the problem is in that method. :/

Comment: @Yupi I have set `focusable` to `true` because Android Studio suggest to do it if you also have `clickable=true`. Even if I remove `focusable=true` the problem is still present.

Comment: you will set focusable to false, clickable to true

Comment: @propoLis If I do that, Android Studio suggests to set `focusable` back to `true`. Also, the problem is not solved.

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: Hey @Grender Did you find the solution? I tried every combination but none worked so far.

Comment: Unfortunately not, @T.M

Comment: your main thread is busy maybe you are doing heavy things such as I/O or network on main thread or maybe your layout is too heavy to inflate that you need to wait some seconds for UI response to click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Inside the **NestedScollView** there was a **RelativeLayout** element needed to be clicked. As long I didn't scroll to the very bottom, the element could be clicked with a single click. If I would reach the bottom I needed two clicks, except if I waited a number of seconds.

The problem proved to be on the default *layout_behavior* of the **AppBarLayout**. I used the custom one suggested in the post below and the problem was solved.

[onClick method not working properly after NestedScrollView scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829976/onclick-method-not-working-properly-after-nestedscrollview-scrolled/47161693#47161693)

Comment: Finally! Thanks a lot! The workaround until it gets fixed can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2). Seen [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774).